# How to return value constantly with thread and infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm making get request in `while(True)` loop in order to constantly receive last price of financial asset and at the same time need rest code of the program to complete independently.

How to make it with threading ? The problem is that I don't know how to integrate infinite loop with value that thread returns

Comment: Learn about threading and queues.

Comment: I recommend this slideshow: https://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/concurrent/Concurrent.pdf

Comment: `threads` can use the same global variable but it may need `lock` to make it safe - so preferred method is to use `Queue` to send data from one thread to another.

Comment: Perhaps instead of a thread you'd prefer to use a Python generator?  That sounds like it might fit your use case:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a value from a thread. This is a producer-consumer pattern. You have to use `Queue`  class from  `queue` module.

Put data from thread in the queue using `Queue.put` method.

Read data from main program using `Queue.get` method

`Queue.get` blocks until there is data in the queue.

read about Queue in here: https://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/concurrent/Concurrent.pdf

or in python.org